# Insufficient Privilege on all pages

Tags: security

I am getting a redirect to `NoAccess.jsp` page after login. I can't access any page.

> Insufficient Privileges
>   You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `API Only User` checkbox is accidentally checked for your User.

See [API Only User permission was set on Profile or Permission Set, causing login issues](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003819&language=en_US). If your profile has "API Only User Checked" then its common to receive this error.

Comment: You probably right. Now I can't uncheck it. I will let u know once I find out. Thanks